# Entity Framework 6 Casscade Deletes and DropForeignKey fails on auto generated constraint name

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Entity Framework 6 Casscading Deletes and DropForeignKey fails on auto generated constraint name

I've been running into a bit of an issue with Entity Framework and cascade deletes between two tables on several one-to-many relationships.

Initially it looked like the correct path to take was to configure the table mappings with the `OnModelCreating` method of `DbContext` turning off cascade delete in a manner such as

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SourceTable>()
        .HasOptional(x => x.NavigationProperty)
        .WithOptionalDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This however did not work throwing an exception stating

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails...

More research lead me to believe that this is because all affected entities must be loaded into the context (eager fetched) so that entity framework may set the FK references to null as part of the transaction. This is not practical for my needs based on the size of the relational graph I'd be dealing with.

My next approach was to modify the `Seed` method of the `Configuration` class and run some arbitrary SQL to drop the Foreign Key constraint and re-add it as a ON DELETE SET NULL constaint. This worked in most cases, however one of the consraints has what appears to be an auto generated unpredicatable name that is diffrent on each call of `Update-Database`. Given that the name can't be predicted the ALTER statments aren't particualr helpful

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"ALTER TABLE SourceTable DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_9405957d032142c3a1227821a9ed1fdf;
                                     ALTER TABLE SourceTable
                                     ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ReasonableName
                                     FOREIGN KEY (NavigationProperty_Id) REFERENCES NavigationProperty (Id) ON DELETE SET NULL;");
```

Finally, I've taken the apprach to use the migration functionality (`DbMigration`) and override `Up` method and leveraging the `DropForeignKey` method along side more explicit SQL to re-add the constraint (EF does not appear to provide a factility to create a ON DELETE SET NULL constraint).

```
DropForeignKey("SourceTable", "NavigationProperty_Id", "DestinationTable");
Sql("ALTER TABLE SourceTable ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ReasonableName FOREIGN KEY (NavigationProperty_Id) REFERENCES DestinationTable (Id) ON DELETE SET NULL;");
```

This works great, up until I encounter the constraint with the auto generate name. At this point the `DropForeignKey` method fails with an exception that is swallowed up by

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data...

When dumping the migration to a SQL script file it becomes clear that the `DropForeignKey` simply generates a FK with a more predictable, non-ambiguous byte stream array.

Is there a proper EF Code First approach to solve the problem of setting FK column values to `null` when deleting the refrenced row, or am I stuck having to hand code SQL in order to gain this functionality?